Locating elements by CSS selector with Selenium
I am trying to scrape some golf data from this page on the PGATour website using Seleniun 3.141.0 in Python 3.12.4. I'm having trouble selecting a paragraph element in the overview section near the top of the page listing the course location (Blaine, Minnesota). Here is my code:
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='chromedriver-win64/chromedriver.exe')
driver.get('https://www.pgatour.com/tournaments/2021/3m-open/R2021525/course-stats')
sel = (
    r'#tabs-\:R79lclf6\:--tabpanel-5 > div > div:nth-child(1) > div > div '
    '> div:nth-child(1) > div > div.css-1xhj18k > div.chakra-stack.css-1qo4jv2'
    ' > div.css-1urj6yl > p'
)
ele = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, sel)
driver.quit()

Executing this results in the error, "no such element: Unable to locate element". I have tried adding waits, both explicit and conditional, and that makes no difference. I have also tried selecting the desired element in the browser console using the selector above, and that works just fine.
I also tried selecting the element a couple levels above with CSS selector
#tabs-\:R79lclf6\:--tabpanel-5 > div > div:nth-child(1) > div > div > div:nth-child(1) > div > div.css-1xhj18k > div.chakra-stack.css-1qo4jv2
Printing out the HTML, I realized some information from the bottom of the page was being picked up (par and yardage under course details). Inspecting the page more closely, I realized that the element
#tabs-\:R79lclf6\:--tabpanel-5 > div
contains two div children with the same class name css-0. The first of these divs contains the element I'm interested in, while the second contains the information from the bottom of the page. But why would
#tabs-\:R79lclf6\:--tabpanel-5 > div > div:nth-child(1)
not navigate into the first div and ignore everything else? Instead, the two div elements seem to get merged together in some way, ultimately causing the element I want to not be found.
I tried finding the element using the copied CSS selector, which I tested in console. I also tried adding waits.
